# docker run can't find local file

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to pass a `.json` file into a Docker container at runtime but it keeps saying that `keys.json was not found` . I need to pass the `.json` file for Google Cloud's: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

After I built the image, I have tried the following commands to no avail:

`pwd = /Users/{username}/Desktop/football-data`

```
docker run \
-e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=keys.json \ 
-v $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:keys.json:ro \
{image_name}:1.0
```

```
docker run \
-e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./keys.json \ 
-v $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:keys.json:ro \
{image_name}:1.0
```

with absolute path as well:

```
docker run \ 
-e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/{username}/Desktop/football-data/keys.json \
-v $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:keys.json:ro \
{image_name}:1.0
```

both error out and say:

`google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File keys.json was not found.`

I'm running this command from the directory in which the image was built and `keys.json` is in the `pwd`

Comment: Is the value `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` a path or "just a string"? If it is "just a string", it might be interpreted as volume name.  --- I am astonished that this command does not exit with an error. I get the message `"... mount path must be absolute.`" and this is also what I would recommend.

Comment: @Turing85 - it's just a string. Trying to follow [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137863/set-google-application-credentials-in-docker) but not sure why it can't find the file.

Comment: Setting `-e SOMEVAR=somevalue` on the `docker run` command line does not mean you can refer to `$SOMEVAR` elsewhere in the command line. The `-e` option sets an environment variable in the container; it doesn't set a variable in your local shell.

Comment: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be a path. In Addition, you can set the volume path like that: -v $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:/key/key.json:ro